# SoLoader: couldn't find DSO to load: libjscexecutor.so

Tags: android, react-native

In debug build also getting crashing while start up. So kindly helps me to fix this issue. I have given the stack trace and error below

```
E/SoLoader: couldn't find DSO to load: libjscexecutor.so
        SoSource 0: com.facebook.soloader.DirectorySoSource[root = /data/app/~~3WAuHN29DqEedaWn79kThw==/com.swellmoney.qa.android-L5-GoM0RqkZ0AsNEYMyIxg==/lib/arm64 flags = 0]
        SoSource 1: com.facebook.soloader.DirectApkSoSource[root = (/data/app/~~3WAuHN29DqEedaWn79kThw==/com.swellmoney.qa.android-L5-GoM0RqkZ0AsNEYMyIxg==/base.apk!/lib/arm64-v8a, )]
        SoSource 2: com.facebook.soloader.DirectorySoSource[root = /system/lib64 flags = 2]
        SoSource 3: com.facebook.soloader.DirectorySoSource[root = /vendor/lib64 flags = 2]
        Native lib dir: /data/app/~~3WAuHN29DqEedaWn79kThw==/com.swellmoney.qa.android-L5-GoM0RqkZ0AsNEYMyIxg==/lib/arm64
     result: 0


V/SoLoader: libhermes-executor-debug.so not found on /data/app/~~3WAuHN29DqEedaWn79kThw==/com.swellmoney.qa.android-L5-GoM0RqkZ0AsNEYMyIxg==/lib/arm64
2022-11-06 22:32:59.211 4616-4616/com.swellmoney.qa.android V/SoLoader: libhermes-executor-debug.so not found on /data/app/~~3WAuHN29DqEedaWn79kThw==/com.swellmoney.qa.android-L5-GoM0RqkZ0AsNEYMyIxg==/base.apk!/lib/arm64-v8a
2022-11-06 22:32:59.211 4616-4616/com.swellmoney.qa.android V/SoLoader: libhermes-executor-debug.so not found on /system/lib64
2022-11-06 22:32:59.211 4616-4616/com.swellmoney.qa.android V/SoLoader: libhermes-executor-debug.so not found on /vendor/lib64
2022-11-06 22:32:59.211 4616-4616/com.swellmoney.qa.android E/SoLoader: couldn't find DSO to load: libhermes-executor-debug.so
        SoSource 0: com.facebook.soloader.DirectorySoSource[root = /data/app/~~3WAuHN29DqEedaWn79kThw==/com.swellmoney.qa.android-L5-GoM0RqkZ0AsNEYMyIxg==/lib/arm64 flags = 0]
        SoSource 1: com.facebook.soloader.DirectApkSoSource[root = (/data/app/~~3WAuHN29DqEedaWn79kThw==/com.swellmoney.qa.android-L5-GoM0RqkZ0AsNEYMyIxg==/base.apk!/lib/arm64-v8a, )]
        SoSource 2: com.facebook.soloader.DirectorySoSource[root = /system/lib64 flags = 2]
        SoSource 3: com.facebook.soloader.DirectorySoSource[root = /vendor/lib64 flags = 2]
        Native lib dir: /data/app/~~3WAuHN29DqEedaWn79kThw==/com.swellmoney.qa.android-L5-GoM0RqkZ0AsNEYMyIxg==/lib/arm64
     result: 0
2022-11-06 22:32:59.212 4616-4616/com.swellmoney.qa.android V/SoLoader: libhermes-executor-release.so not found on /data/app/~~3WAuHN29DqEedaWn79kThw==/com.swellmoney.qa.android-L5-GoM0RqkZ0AsNEYMyIxg==/lib/arm64
2022-11-06 22:32:59.237 4616-4616/com.swellmoney.qa.android D/SoLoader: libhermes-executor-release.so found on /data/app/~~3WAuHN29DqEedaWn79kThw==/com.swellmoney.qa.android-L5-GoM0RqkZ0AsNEYMyIxg==/base.apk!/lib/arm64-v8a
2022-11-06 22:32:59.262 4616-4661/com.swellmoney.qa.android I/FA: Tag Manager is not found and thus will not be used
2022-11-06 22:32:59.306 4616-4669/com.swellmoney.qa.android V/SoLoader: libfbjni.so not found on /data/app/~~3WAuHN29DqEedaWn79kThw==/com.swellmoney.qa.android-L5-GoM0RqkZ0AsNEYMyIxg==/lib/arm64
2022-11-06 22:32:59.308 4616-4669/com.swellmoney.qa.android V/SoLoader: libandroid.so not found on /data/app/~~3WAuHN29DqEedaWn79kThw==/com.swellmoney.qa.android-L5-GoM0RqkZ0AsNEYMyIxg==/lib/arm64
2022-11-06 22:32:59.308 4616-4669/com.swellmoney.qa.android V/SoLoader: libandroid.so not found on /data/app/~~3WAuHN29DqEedaWn79kThw==/com.swellmoney.qa.android-L5-GoM0RqkZ0AsNEYMyIxg==/base.apk!/lib/arm64-v8a
2022-11-06 22:32:59.308 4616-4669/com.swellmoney.qa.android D/SoLoader: libandroid.so found on /system/lib64
2022-11-06 22:32:59.308 4616-4669/com.swellmoney.qa.android D/SoLoader: libandroid.so loaded implicitly
2022-11-06 22:32:59.309 4616-4669/com.swellmoney.qa.android D/SoLoader: libfbjni.so found on /data/app/~~3WAuHN29DqEedaWn79kThw==/com.swellmoney.qa.android-L5-GoM0RqkZ0AsNEYMyIxg==/base.apk!/lib/arm64-v8a
2022-11-06 22:32:59.309 4616-4669/com.swellmoney.qa.android V/SoLoader: libflipper.so not found on /data/app/~~3WAuHN29DqEedaWn79kThw==/com.swellmoney.qa.android-L5-GoM0RqkZ0AsNEYMyIxg==/lib/arm64
2022-11-06 22:32:59.329 4616-4669/com.swellmoney.qa.android D/SoLoader: libflipper.so found on /data/app/~~3WAuHN29DqEedaWn79kThw==/com.swellmoney.qa.android-L5-GoM0RqkZ0AsNEYMyIxg==/base.apk!/lib/arm64-v8a
2022-11-06 22:32:59.338 4616-4616/com.swellmoney.qa.android W/oney.qa.androi: Accessing hidden field Landroid/view/View;->mKeyedTags:Landroid/util/SparseArray; (greylist, reflection, allowed)
2022-11-06 22:32:59.338 4616-4616/com.swellmoney.qa.android W/oney.qa.androi: Accessing hidden field Landroid/view/View;->mListenerInfo:Landroid/view/View$ListenerInfo; (greylist, reflection, allowed)
2022-11-06 22:32:59.339 4616-4616/com.swellmoney.qa.android W/oney.qa.androi: Accessing hidden field Landroid/view/View$ListenerInfo;->mOnClickListener:Landroid/view/View$OnClickListener; (greylist, reflection, allowed)
2022-11-06 22:32:59.341 4616-4616/com.swellmoney.qa.android I/flipper: flipper: FlipperClient::addPlugin Inspector
2022-11-06 22:32:59.341 4616-4616/com.swellmoney.qa.android I/flipper: flipper: FlipperClient::addPlugin React
2022-11-06 22:32:59.342 4616-4616/com.swellmoney.qa.android I/flipper: flipper: FlipperClient::addPlugin Databases
2022-11-06 22:32:59.343 4616-4616/com.swellmoney.qa.android I/flipper: flipper: FlipperClient::addPlugin Preferences
2022-11-06 22:32:59.343 4616-4616/com.swellmoney.qa.android I/flipper: flipper: FlipperClient::addPlugin CrashReporter
2022-11-06 22:32:59.344 4616-4616/com.swellmoney.qa.android I/flipper: flipper: FlipperClient::addPlugin Network
2022-11-06 22:32:59.444 4616-4616/com.swellmoney.qa.android W/oney.qa.androi: Accessing hidden method Landroid/view/View;->computeFitSystemWindows(Landroid/graphics/Rect;Landroid/graphics/Rect;)Z (greylist, reflection, allowed)
2022-11-06 22:32:59.445 4616-4616/com.swellmoney.qa.android W/oney.qa.androi: Accessing hidden method Landroid/view/ViewGroup;->makeOptionalFitsSystemWindows()V (greylist, reflection, allowed)
2022-11-06 22:32:59.474 4616-4616/com.swellmoney.qa.android W/unknown:ReactNative: Packager connection already open, nooping.
2022-11-06 22:32:59.491 4616-4616/com.swellmoney.qa.android I/Gralloc4: mapper 4.x is not supported
2022-11-06 22:32:59.492 4616-4616/com.swellmoney.qa.android D/HostConnection: createUnique: call
2022-11-06 22:32:59.493 4616-4616/com.swellmoney.qa.android D/HostConnection: HostConnection::get() New Host Connection established 0xb400007d74b57c10, tid 4616
2022-11-06 22:32:59.494 4616-4616/com.swellmoney.qa.android D/goldfish-address-space: allocate: Ask for block of size 0x100
2022-11-06 22:32:59.494 4616-4616/com.swellmoney.qa.android D/goldfish-address-space: allocate: ioctl allocate returned offset 0x1f3ff8000 size 0x8000
2022-11-06 22:32:59.496 4616-4616/com.swellmoney.qa.android D/HostConnection: HostComposition ext ANDROID_EMU_CHECKSUM_HELPER_v1 ANDROID_EMU_native_sync_v2 ANDROID_EMU_native_sync_v3 ANDROID_EMU_native_sync_v4 ANDROID_EMU_dma_v1 ANDROID_EMU_direct_mem ANDROID_EMU_host_composition_v1 ANDROID_EMU_host_composition_v2 ANDROID_EMU_vulkan ANDROID_EMU_deferred_vulkan_commands ANDROID_EMU_vulkan_null_optional_strings ANDROID_EMU_vulkan_create_resources_with_requirements ANDROID_EMU_YUV_Cache ANDROID_EMU_vulkan_ignored_handles ANDROID_EMU_has_shared_slots_host_memory_allocator ANDROID_EMU_vulkan_free_memory_sync ANDROID_EMU_vulkan_shader_float16_int8 ANDROID_EMU_vulkan_async_queue_submit ANDROID_EMU_sync_buffer_data ANDROID_EMU_read_color_buffer_dma GL_OES_EGL_image_external_essl3 GL_OES_vertex_array_object GL_KHR_texture_compression_astc_ldr ANDROID_EMU_host_side_tracing ANDROID_EMU_gles_max_version_3_0 
2022-11-06 22:33:00.520 4616-4671/com.swellmoney.qa.android V/SoLoader: libreactnativejni.so not found on /data/app/~~3WAuHN29DqEedaWn79kThw==/com.swellmoney.qa.android-L5-GoM0RqkZ0AsNEYMyIxg==/lib/arm64
2022-11-06 22:33:00.530 4616-4671/com.swellmoney.qa.android D/SoLoader: libreactnativejni.so found on /data/app/~~3WAuHN29DqEedaWn79kThw==/com.swellmoney.qa.android-L5-GoM0RqkZ0AsNEYMyIxg==/base.apk!/lib/arm64-v8a
2022-11-06 22:33:01.169 4616-4694/com.swellmoney.qa.android W/oney.qa.androi: Accessing hidden method Landroid/os/WorkSource;->add(I)Z (greylist,test-api, reflection, allowed)
2022-11-06 22:33:01.169 4616-4694/com.swellmoney.qa.android W/oney.qa.androi: Accessing hidden method Landroid/os/WorkSource;->add(ILjava/lang/String;)Z (greylist,test-api, reflection, allowed)
2022-11-06 22:33:01.169 4616-4694/com.swellmoney.qa.android W/oney.qa.androi: Accessing hidden method Landroid/os/WorkSource;->get(I)I (greylist, reflection, allowed)
2022-11-06 22:33:01.169 4616-4694/com.swellmoney.qa.android W/oney.qa.androi: Accessing hidden method Landroid/os/WorkSource;->getName(I)Ljava/lang/String; (greylist, reflection, allowed)
2022-11-06 22:33:02.406 4616-4616/com.swellmoney.qa.android D/InstallReferrerState: OK
2022-11-06 22:33:02.545 4616-4703/com.swellmoney.qa.android A/libc: Fatal signal 11 (SIGSEGV), code 1 (SEGV_MAPERR), fault addr 0x7200726f727255 in tid 4703 (mqt_js), pid 4616 (oney.qa.android)
```

The below code I tried and getting crash while start my app in debug too. I have given the config below

project level build.gradle

```
buildscript {
    ext {
        buildToolsVersion = "33.0.0"
        minSdkVersion = 24
        compileSdkVersion = 33
        targetSdkVersion = 33
        ndkVersion = "20.1.5948944"
        supportLibVersion = "33.0.0"
    }
    repositories {
        google()
        mavenCentral()

        jcenter()
        flatDir {
            dirs 'libs'
        }
    }
    dependencies {
        classpath("com.android.tools.build:gradle:4.1.3")
        classpath 'com.google.gms:google-services:4.3.10'
        classpath 'com.google.firebase:firebase-crashlytics-gradle:2.8.1'
        classpath 'com.dipien:bye-bye-jetifier:1.2.1'
    }
}

def REACT_NATIVE_VERSION = new File(['node', '--print',"JSON.parse(require('fs').readFileSync(require.resolve('react-native/package.json'), 'utf-8')).version"].execute(null, rootDir).text.trim())

allprojects {
    configurations.all {
        resolutionStrategy {
            force "com.facebook.react:react-native:" + REACT_NATIVE_VERSION
        }
    }
    repositories {
        mavenLocal()
        jcenter()

        google()
        flatDir {
            dirs 'libs'
        }
        maven {   url "https://maven.google.com"  }
        maven {
            // All of React Native (JS, Obj-C sources, Android binaries) is installed from npm
            url("$rootDir/../node_modules/react-native/android")
        }
        maven {
            // Android JSC is installed from npm
            url("$rootDir/../node_modules/jsc-android/dist")

        }
        mavenCentral()
        maven { url 'https://www.jitpack.io' }
        maven {
            url "$rootDir/../node_modules/detox/Detox-android"
        }
        maven {
            url 'https://sdk.withpersona.com/android/releases'
        }

    }
}
```

And app/build.gradle

```
project.ext.react = [
        enableHermes: true,  // clean and rebuild if changing
        bundleInBeta: true,
        devDisabledInBeta: true,
        hermesFlagsForVariant: {
            def v -> v.name.toLowerCase().contains('release') || v.name.toLowerCase().contains('debug') ? ['-w'] : []
        },
        deleteDebugFilesForVariant: {
            def v -> v.name.toLowerCase().contains('release') || v.name.toLowerCase().contains('debug')
        },
]



 

    flavorDimensions "swellApp"
    productFlavors {

        qa {
            
            signingConfig signingConfigs.qaConfig
            buildConfigField "boolean", "QA", "true"
           
        }

        prod{
           
            signingConfig signingConfigs.prodConfig
            buildConfigField "boolean", "QA", "false"
           

    }

}


dependencies {
    implementation fileTree(dir: "libs", include: ["*.jar"])
    //noinspection GradleDynamicVersion
    implementation "com.facebook.react:react-native:" +REACT_NATIVE_VERSION // From node_modules
    implementation 'com.android.support:multidex:1.0.3'
    implementation 'com.facebook.soloader:soloader:0.10.4'
    implementation "androidx.swiperefreshlayout:swiperefreshlayout:1.1.0"
    implementation "org.webkit:android-jsc:+"
    debugImplementation("com.facebook.flipper:flipper:${FLIPPER_VERSION}") {
        exclude group:'com.facebook.fbjni'
    }
    implementation 'com.google.firebase:firebase-storage:20.0.0'
    implementation project(':react-native-secure-key-store')
    debugImplementation("com.facebook.flipper:flipper-network-plugin:${FLIPPER_VERSION}") {
        exclude group:'com.facebook.flipper'
        exclude group:'com.squareup.okhttp3', module:'okhttp'
    }

    debugImplementation("com.facebook.flipper:flipper-fresco-plugin:${FLIPPER_VERSION}") {
        exclude group:'com.facebook.flipper'
    }

    if (enableHermes) {
        implementation("com.facebook.react:hermes-engine:+") {
            exclude group:'com.facebook.fbjni'
                 }

    } else {
        implementation jscFlavor
    }
    androidTestImplementation('com.wix:detox:+')
    implementation ("androidx.appcompat:appcompat:1.3.1") {
        version {
            strictly '1.3.1'
        }
    }
}
```

FYI: I am using product flavor